# Chain 2 imagemagick commands

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation

I would like to add a logo and some text to an image.

I can achieve this through the following:

```
// Add logo
composite -geometry +10+20 logo.png input.jpg \
    output_with_logo.jpg

// Add text
convert output_with_logo.jpg  -font Arial -pointsize 20 \
    -draw "fill black  text 20,50 'Test'" \
    final.jpg
```

However I'm wondering if I can chain these 2 commands together so I can work from the same source file at once, instead of saving out staged versions of the image.

I've tried:

```
convert -font Arial -pointsize 20 \
    -draw "fill black  text 20,50 'Test'" \
    -composite -geometry +10+20 input.jpg logo.png \
    final.jpg
```

However this creates 2 "Test" strings on the image

Comment: What a *"jolly"* question, Green Giant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
convert input.jpg logo.jpg -geometry +10+20 -composite -font Arial -pointsize 20 -draw "fill black  text 20,50 'Test'" final.jpg
```

Rather than use the `composite` command which won't let you add text, use the `convert` command and its `-composite` operator which does the same thing. So, I am saying:

```
composite A.jpg B.jpg result.jpg = convert A.jpg B.jpg -composite result.jpg
```

Then, once you have done the compositing, you can add the text afterwards - exactly as you had it.